# NSDate Month Difference

Tags: ios, nsdate

I am facing one problem. I am fetching the start date and end date from the user. I am showing those months in the UI.

**First question:** If the user gives different dates from the same month (like 2013-01-10 and 2013-01-25) and I try to get the difference of the two dates at that time, the month difference is showing me zero month. How can I get the month difference including the start date month and end date month?

**Second question:** If the user gives different dates like 2013-01-29 and 2013-02-01, it still gives me zero month difference. How can I overcome these two problems? In both situations I am getting the same result. How can I differentiate?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show us your codes ?

Comment: sorry i can't.violation of company rule.So...

Comment: if you can't post codes, you shouldn't ask here. Alternatively, you can just post a line or two to illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at this project on Github:

[MTDates NSDate categories](https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/MTDates)

Even if you can't use the whole library, you can look at the code making it happen. There's a method that should be just what you need:

```
- (NSInteger)mt_monthsSinceDate:(NSDate *)date;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can give this a try

```
NSString *fromDateString = @"2013-01-10";
NSString *toDateString = @"2013-01-25";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate * fromDate = [formatter dateFromString:fromDateString];
NSDate *toDate      = [formatter dateFromString:toDateString];

NSCalendar *calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSUInteger units = (NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit);
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calender components:units fromDate:fromDate toDate:toDate options:0];

NSString *duration = nil;
if (dateComponents.month) {
     //Different months
    duration = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d months",dateComponents.month];
}else{
    //Same month
    duration = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d days",dateComponents.day];
}

NSLog(@"Duration : %@",duration);
```